# Why does lapply() not retain my data.table keys?

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a bunch of data.tables in a list. I want to apply `unique()` to each data.table in my list, but doing so destroys all my data.table keys.

Here's an example:

```
A <- data.table(a = rep(c("a","b"), each = 3), b = runif(6), key = "a")
B <- data.table(x = runif(6), b = runif(6), key = "x")

blah <- unique(A)
```

Here, `blah` still has a key, and everything is right in the world:

```
key(blah)

# [1] "a"
```

But if I add the data.tables to a list and use `lapply()`, the keys get destroyed:

```
dt.list <- list(A, B)

unique.list <- lapply(dt.list, unique) # Keys destroyed here

lapply(unique.list, key) 

# [[1]]
# NULL

# [[2]]
# NULL
```

This probably has to do with me not really understanding what it means for keys to be assigned "by reference," as I've had other problems with keys disappearing.

So:

- **Why does lapply not retain my keys?**
- What does it mean to say keys are assigned "by reference"?
- Should I even  be storing data.tables in a list?
- How can I safely store/manipulate data.tables without fear of losing my keys?

**EDIT:**

For what it's worth, the dreaded `for` loop works just fine, too:

```
unique.list <- list()

for (i in 1:length(dt.list)) {
  unique.list[[i]] <- unique(dt.list[[i]])
}

lapply(unique.list, key)

# [[1]]
# [1] "a"

# [[2]]
# [1] "x"
```

But this is R, and `for` loops are *evil*.

Comment: interestingly, `unique.list[[1]] != unique(A)`.   My guess, though just plainly a guess, is that perhaps what is getting called in the lapply statement is the `{base}` unique and not the `{data.table}` `unique`.

Comment: I think you're right. I just noticed that – along with keys being destroyed – `unique` isn't even doing its job when passed through `lapply`

Comment: @PaulMurray +1 Good question, but _destroy_ seems a little strong. It doesn't _retain_ them in this case.

Comment: @MatthewDowle "edited for language"

Comment: or you should have gone all the way like "data.table and lapply annihilate table keys"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interestingly, notice the difference between these two different results

```
lapply(dt.list, unique) 
lapply(dt.list, function(x) unique(x))
```

If you use the latter, the results are as you would expect.

---

The seemingly unexpected behavior is due to the fact that the first `lapply` statement is
  invoking `unique.data.frame` (ie from `{base}`) while the second is invoking `unique.data.table`

Comment: Wow, thanks. And *weird*. This works as a solution, but I still want to know what's going on. Am I the only one that wants to store data.tables in lists? I'm going to submit this as a [bug report](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?atid=975&group_id=240&func=browse) – think that's fair?

Comment: @Plmrry I think when you store your `data.table`s as list, you lose a large benefit of what data.table offers, namely the memory efficiency by avoiding unnecessary duplication.   Personally, I store a list of the **names** of my data.tables and then grab them by `get(` *name* `)`.  A bit uglier code, but faster.

Comment: @Plmrry as for the bug report, it might not be a bug, but just the way that `match.fun()` works.  I couldnt say though

Comment: Yeah, it's looking like I should just abandon storing `data.table`s in lists. I have a couple functions that scrape XML and spit out a list of relational tables, but I suppose I should just keep them as-is in the environment and save them all as `RData`... I'm still searching for "best practices" when it comes to dealing with a lot of data tables (or frames), especially when I want to be able to pass them as arguments.

Comment: @PaulMurray I tend to have one large table rather than a list of many smaller ones. For something like scraping I'd probably scrape into a `list` of `data.table`, yes, but then use `rbindlist` to create the big one. `insert()` rows by reference is on the wish list.

Comment: @MatthewDowle Well, these are separate relational tables, so I can't `rbind` them. For example, my function might scrape "schools" and "students" and "states," each of which is related to the other through a relational table, e.g. "schools.students."

Comment: @MatthewDowle I did not realize there was an `rbindlist`!

Comment: @RicardoSaporta  What else didn't you know you didn't know? Have you seen `unknownR::unk()`? :-)  A list of packages such as `data.table` can be passed to it.

Comment: @PaulMurray In that case you're right then. I hadn't considered a use case like that. Kind of a dynamic database by the sounds of it. If you need enhancements happy to add them. Other than this `lapply` issue seems an R thing, so I'm not sure what we can do. Unless, we mask `lapply` itself (or you could locally).

Comment: @MatthewDowle I dont know ;)

Answer (score 6):

Good question. It turns out that it's documented in `?lapply` (see Note section) :

> For historical reasons, the calls created by lapply are unevaluated,
>   and code has been written (e.g. bquote) that relies on this. This
>   means that the recorded call is always of the form FUN(X[[0L]], ...),
>   with 0L replaced by the current integer index. This is not normally a
>   problem, but it can be if FUN uses sys.call or match.call or if it is
>   a primitive function that makes use of the call. *This means that it is
>   often safer to call primitive functions with a wrapper, so that e.g.
>   lapply(ll, function(x) is.numeric(x)) is required in R 2.7.1 to ensure
>   that method dispatch for is.numeric occurs correctly.*