# Object disappears from namespace in function

Tags: r

I am writing a wrapper to combine any number of datasets row-wise. Since some may have unique variables, I am first restricting to the variables in the data.

My function works like this

```
rcombine <- function(List, Vars) {
  List2 <- lapply(List, subset, select=Vars)
  Reduce(rbind, List2)
}
```

When I run the code directly, it works. But in the function, my variable `Vars` disappears.

For instance:

```
x <- data.frame('a'=sample(LETTERS, 10), 'b'=sample(LETTERS, 10), 'c'=sample(LETTERS, 10))
y <- data.frame('a'=sample(LETTERS, 10), 'b'=sample(LETTERS, 10), 'e'=sample(LETTERS, 10))

rcombine(list(x, y), c('a', 'b'))
```

gives me:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Vars' not found
```

but running:

```
List <- list(x, y)
Reduce(rbind, lapply(List, subset, select=c('a','b')))
```

Works. I can print `Vars` from the function, but inside `lapply` it disappears. What is going on?

Comment: Read the Warning in `?subset`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subset` really shouldn't be used for these types of things.  From the help page

> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For
>   programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like
>   [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset
>   can have unanticipated consequences.

For your particular problem I don't see why just replacing subset with directly using "[" would be a problem.

```
rcombine <- function(List, Vars) {
  List2 <- lapply(List, "[", i= , j = Vars, drop = FALSE) # here is the change
  Reduce(rbind, List2)
}

# alternatively...
rcombine <- function(List, Vars) {
  List2 <- lapply(List, function(x){x[, Vars, drop = FALSE]}) # here is the change
  Reduce(rbind, List2)
}

x <- data.frame('a'=sample(LETTERS, 10), 'b'=sample(LETTERS, 10), 'c'=sample(LETTERS, 10))
y <- data.frame('a'=sample(LETTERS, 10), 'b'=sample(LETTERS, 10), 'e'=sample(LETTERS, 10))

rcombine(list(x, y), c('a', 'b'))
```

Comment: That does fix the problem. A bit sad because I feel like `subset` helps make the code more readable, especially for non-programmers. Looks like the reason why it fails is that the `subset.data.frame` method uses an `eval` statement in it's setup, which seems like a likely culprit.

Comment: awesome answer that really highlights the quirks of R!

Comment: Calling primitive functions (e.g. `[`) like this is a bit risky - I think you're safer to use an anonymous function: `lapply(List, function(j) x[, j, drop = FALSE])`.  Also note `drop = FALSE` otherwise the code doesn't work when `Vars` is length one.

Comment: @ashkan subset is for interactive analysis, not for programming.

Comment: @hadley Can you elaborate on why you think calling `[` like this is 'risky'?

Comment: @Dason -- see the *note* section of `?lapply`, especially *This means that it is often safer to call primitive functions with a wrapper, so that e.g. lapply(ll, function(x) is.numeric(x)) is required in R 2.7.1 to ensure that method dispatch for is.numeric occurs correctly.* For an example on SO see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928278/why-does-lapply-not-retain-my-data-table-keys

Comment: @dason and because primitive functions don't do named matching, so `lapply(List, "[", j = Vars)` doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @hadley If `[` doesn't do name based matching, why does Dason's example work?

Comment: @ashkan positional matching works as well.  You can leave off the i= and the j= in the example and it will still work.  The issue Hadley brings up is that even if you did `j=Vars, i=` it wouldn't matter and it would think Vars was specifying rows.  I put the i= and j= in there to make it a little more clear what was supposed to happen.

Comment: @Dason I see, I thought by positional matching, we were referring to the column index for `Vars` in the various `data.frames` in `List`. I can see how that would be confusing.